# How to put dates in charjs angular 17?

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular17

I am pretty new to angular, I have this code on my component:

```
import { Component, inject, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chart',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './chart.component.html',
  styleUrl: './chart.component.css'
})
export class ChartComponent {
  title = 'ng-chart';
  chart: any = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chart = new Chart('canvas', {
      type: 'scatter',
      data: {
        labels: ["2010-01-02 05:06:07","2010-01-03 05:06:07","2010-01-04 05:06:07","2010-01-05 05:06:07"],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Transactions',
          data: [{
            x: "2010-01-01 05:06:07",
            y: 10
          }, {
            x: "2010-01-02 05:06:07",
            y: 5
          }, {
            x: "2010-01-03 05:06:07",
            y: 5.5
          }],
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
        },{
        data: [{
          x: "2010-01-04 05:06:07",
          y: 7
        }, {
          x: "2010-01-05 05:06:07",
          y: 7
        }, {
          x: "2010-01-06 05:06:07",
          y: 6.5
        }],
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(125, 99, 132)'
        }],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true
          },
          x:{
            type: 'time'
          }
        }
      },
    });
  }
}
```

but it doesn't show nothing, if i put `type: 'linear'`  on x type, it shows me a graph with 0 as starting point in x and 1 as last element.
How may I have dates on x axes?
I have tried with the documentation but i haven't found an example that fits my requirements

Comment: I can't approve it at the moment, but the dates you entered are just strings. It is possible, that chart.js can't interpret the strings as dates. Try using the Date type or timestamps. If the dates are displayed wrongly, you should be able to transform the data somehow. I'm on my phone, so I can't check how do do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to import `chartjs-adapter-moment` which made it start working, first I installed with

```
npm install moment chartjs-adapter-moment --save
```

Then I added the import like below!

```
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';
```

Then finally, I changed to a view child for the canvas ref, which worked great!

full code

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
import 'zone.js';
import 'chartjs-adapter-moment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <canvas #canvas></canvas>
  `,
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('canvas') canvas!: ElementRef<any>;
  title = 'ng-chart';
  chart: any = [];

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.chart = new Chart(this.canvas.nativeElement, {
      type: 'scatter',
      data: {
        labels: [
          '2010-01-02 05:06:07',
          '2010-01-03 05:06:07',
          '2010-01-04 05:06:07',
          '2010-01-05 05:06:07',
        ],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Transactions',
            data: [
              {
                x: '2010-01-01 05:06:07',
                y: 10,
              },
              {
                x: '2010-01-02 05:06:07',
                y: 5,
              },
              {
                x: '2010-01-03 05:06:07',
                y: 5.5,
              },
            ],
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          },
          {
            data: [
              {
                x: '2010-01-04 05:06:07',
                y: 7,
              },
              {
                x: '2010-01-05 05:06:07',
                y: 7,
              },
              {
                x: '2010-01-06 05:06:07',
                y: 6.5,
              },
            ],
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(125, 99, 132)',
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
          x: {
            type: 'time',
          },
        },
      },
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-l3kjyj?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=package.json,src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)